# what is the df.coalesce(1) means?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, hdfs, parquet

I used spark with python so i need to save parquet file included spark result

```
df
.coalesce(1)
.write
.save(save_path, format='parquet', mode='append'))
```

this is Collect data and save to HDFS as parquet format code

so i am curious that if i ran the spark about 30 parquet files 
the spark result will be save only one parquet file or not

if someone know that the principal plz teach me 
also is this code is correct or not for save only one parquet files.

thank you

Answer (score 7):

**Coalesce** uses existing partitions to minimize the amount of data that's shuffled.

---

**Repartition** creates new partitions and does a full shuffle. 
coalesce results in partitions with different amounts of data (sometimes partitions that have much different sizes) and repartition results in roughly equal sized partitions.

---

In terms of **performance** of the operation, coalesce is more efficient. Repartition might be a choice in case you may require equal sized partitions for doing further processing

---

For the example you provided **coalesce()** is the better option coalesce() is indeed the best option always when you need to set the number of partitions = 1

Your code is correct and should working only generating one datafile as output

Comment: This is a correct and clear information, just as an additional comment is that you should be careful when using `.coalesce(1)` because all the data will be sent to driver and can cause a memory error if it doesn't fit.

Answer (score 5):

**Coalesce is a method to partition the data in a dataframe**. This is mainly used to **reduce the number of partitions in a dataframe**.

You can refer to this [link](https://medium.com/@mrpowers/managing-spark-partitions-with-coalesce-and-repartition-4050c57ad5c4) and [link](https://datanoon.com/blog/spark_repartition_coalesce/) for more details on `coalesce` and `repartition`

And yes if you use `df.coalesce(1)` it'll write only one file (in your case one parquet file)